# MySQL SELECT w/ PHP through date barrier

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database where I'd like to select certain prices for certain hours:

```
 id | slot_date  | slot_time | slot_price | hotel_id | room_type_id | status
 +--+------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+------+
 1  | 2014-10-29 | 21:00:00  | 5          | 5        | 6            | 0
 2  | 2014-10-29 | 22:00:00  | 10         | 5        | 6            | 0
 3  | 2014-10-29 | 23:00:00  | 12         | 5        | 6            | 0
 4  | 2014-10-30 | 00:00:00  | 22         | 5        | 6            | 0
 5  | 2014-10-30 | 01:00:00  | 22         | 5        | 6            | 0
 6  | 2014-10-30 | 02:00:00  | 22         | 5        | 6            | 0
 7  | 2014-10-30 | 03:00:00  | 22         | 5        | 6            | 0
```

I want to grab the prices for certain hours and I'm doing it with this:

```
SELECT * from rn_slots_prices WHERE hotel_id = '5' AND room_type_id = '6' AND slot_time >= '21:00:00' AND slot_time <= '23:00:00' AND slot_date = '2014-10-29' AND status = '0'
```

That gives me the prices for certain hours. Now the problem is, if the selected hourse cross the date barrier, so from 23:00 to 02:00 am. I tried the following (with a php workaround checking end and start date), but it doesn't work?

```
SELECT * from rn_slots_prices WHERE hotel_id = '5' AND room_type_id = '6' AND (slot_time >= '23:00:00' AND slot_time <= '23:59:00' AND slot_date = '2014-10-29') OR (slot_time <= '02:00:00' AND slot_time >= '00:00:00' AND slot_date = '2014-10-30') AND status = '0' ORDER BY slot_time ASC
```

The result is always zero.
I can find a way around with PHP (I think), but there must be another way?

Comment: Can you modify the table data?  A datetime column would be preferred.  Then you can do queries like `slot_date BETWEEN '2014-10-29 23:00:00' AND '2014-10-30 01:59:59'`

Comment: Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to compare date or time as like numeric number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date/time into unix timestamp, so you can compare:

```
SELECT * from rn_slots_prices WHERE hotel_id = '5' AND room_type_id = '6' AND status = '0'
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(slot_date,' ',slot_time)) BETWEEN
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-29 23:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-30 02:00:00')
ORDER BY slot_time ASC
```

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you are using the same table/database you posted?

Comment: Please see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ac45/1 @Fathah Rehman P as well

Comment: @PrimuS the query is correct, the problem is that you are using `room_type_id=6` and this data doesn't exist in the fiddle (but it does in the example you originally posted).

Comment: I missed that, but seems not to be the problem. Here new fiddle with updated query dates: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47820/1

Comment: SORRY, now the query had the wrong dates!! Works now... It all comes down to me having a wrong db. Thanks everyone!